# TADOQuery does not return any record

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, delphi-7, ado

I am using Delphi 7 and I have a table named `Table_1` which has two fields say, `IMageCode Varchar(50)`, `ActImage [Blob in Oracle, VarBinary(Max) in SQL Server]`, it has four records inserted including images and respective image code.

When I write a SQL as below in Oracle:

```
Select * from Table_1 where Upper(ImageCode) ='SUNSET'
```

TADOQuery doesn't return any record, when I check `TADOQuery.RecordCount` it shows `0`, when I try to see `TADOQuery.IsEmpty` it says `True`. Then same query when I execute in the Oracle editor it returns one record as expected, but in delphi the TADOQuery doen't return any record.

But when I write following simple sql for the oracle database, it returns all four records using TADOQuery:

```
Select * from Table_1
```

I don't find any issue in SQL server database, as discussed above using TADOQuery.

```
ADOConnection.Connected := False; 
ADOConnection.LoginPrompt := False; 
ADOConnection.ConnectionString := <Connection String>; 
ADOConnection.Connected := True; 
ADOQuery1.Connection := ADOConnection; 
with ADOQuery1 do begin 
  Active := False; 
  SQL.Clear; 
  //SqL.Add('Select * from Table_1 where Upper(ImageCode) = ' +    QuotedStr(Uppercase(Trim(edtImageCode.Text)))); 
  SqL.Add('Select * from Table_1 where Upper(ImageCode) = ''SUNSET'''); 
  Active := True; 
end;
```

Could anybody put focus what could be the issue?

Comment: ADOConnection.Connected := False;
ADOConnection.LoginPrompt  := False;
ADOConnection.ConnectionString := <Connection String>;
ADOConnection.Connected := True;
ADOQuery1.Connection := ADOConnection;

with ADOQuery1 do
begin
  Active := False;
  SQL.Clear;
  //SqL.Add('Select * from Table_1 where Upper(ImageCode) = ' + QuotedStr(Uppercase(Trim(edtImageCode.Text))));
  SqL.Add('Select * from Table_1 where Upper(ImageCode) = ''SUNSET''');    Active := True;
end;

Comment: I tried Ctrl+K, but no change in formatting, anyway I would keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: The Microsoft Win32 Oracle driver for ADO that you may be using, doesn't support blobs, which may be the reason why this fails. Do you get a record if you specify just the field `IMageCode` instead of `*` in the field list?

Comment: ADOConnection.ConnectionString := 'Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info = True;Password=<Pwd>;User ID=<User Id>;Data Source=<Data Source Name>'; //I uaed this connection string

Comment: When I say ImageCode without "where" condition it gives four records, but the moment i use "where" condition it gives zero records.

Comment: What happens if you add "WHERE 1=1" or "WHERE ImageCode ='sunset'" i.e. with the character case of the ImageCode and without using Upper() function?

Comment: When I add "WHERE 1=1" then it returns 4 records, but when I add "WHERE ImageCode ='Sunset'" as it is saved in the db, then TADOQuery returns "0" record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved, I tried making "ImageCode" as a primary key, and now TADOQuery is returning the peroper record count i.e. 1 as expected. Previously there was no primary key, but still, if there is primary key or not TADOQuery should return the required data sets.

Any guess ?